# data refresh after every 24 hours

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, websphere

I have developed an application using websphere6.1 which is required to query the database(oracle) after one day(24hours) periodically. But the it is not getting executed properly since I am getting an dataaccess exception.I am using connection pooling and spring jdbc.I wonder why this is happening since the test for smaller time intervals (say) 25 mins is running successfully.Is the connection with database getting dropped or do I need to adjust some parameters to get the output .

Comment: Had you tried finding out something like Execution Time-Out in your Database Tools, set it's value to zero. That might can solve the issue concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I had spend a while trying to figure out how to fix it. Finally, in my case the problem was related to stale connections. I saw StaleConnectionException in SystemOut.log after 24 hours. I found the answers [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247168#SCETroubleshooting).

Good luck!

Comment: Have also encountered a similar problem. You can adjust timeouts and/or do dummy queries to keep the connection alive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am confused whether the connection becoming stale one of the root cause of dataaccess exception in Spring

Comment: Also one more strange thing is that if the application fires an altogether  different query on the database we get a proper response.But if the application fires the query to be executed after 24 hrs periodically then we are not getting the response.

Comment: The app server manages pool of connections. It utilizes connections from the pool again and again. Your application requests the connection from the pool in order to run some query. The connection it gets from the pool might become stale if not configured to run test that check that the connection is still alive.

Comment: ...and yes, the connection becoming stale can be a root cause of DataAccessException in Spring,

Comment: I am using connection pooling.Is there any way by whih I can explicitly return a connection logically  back to the pool by statement such as conn.close?